# Rails: filter by matching between models columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

firstly you can check all github files in here:
[link](https://github.com/MswordArt/FBC/tree/master/app/controllers)

I have two model these have same filter columns.
`User` model have `:country id` also `Poll` model have `:country_id`

in index page, i need filter show polls these have same `country_id` by `current_user`.

my polls controller is below:

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :check_exist


  def index

  @polls = Poll.all
 @person = Person.find_by_poll_id(params[:poll_id])

 if @poll.person.country_id == current_user.person.country_id
  @polls = Poll.order('created_at DESC')
else
  flash[:warning] = 'there is no polls these matching by your countries'
end

  end


  def show     
     @poll = Poll.includes(:vote_options).find_by_id(params[:id])
    @vote = Vote.new

  end

  def new
    @poll = current_user.polls.build
     @person = @poll.build_person
  end

  def edit
    @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @person = Person.find_by_poll_id(params[:poll_id])
  end

  def update
  @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @person = Person.find_by_poll_id(params[:poll_id])

   if @poll.update_attributes(poll_params) && @poll.person.update(people_edit_params)
    flash[:success] = 'Poll was updated!'
    redirect_to polls_path
    else
    render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @poll = current_user.polls.new(poll_params)
    @person = @poll.build_person(people_edit_params)
    @person_user_id = nil
    if @poll.save

      flash[:success] = 'Poll was created!'
      redirect_to polls_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @poll.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Poll was destroyed!'
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Error destroying poll...'
    end
    redirect_to polls_path
  end

  private

  def poll_params
    params.require(:poll).permit(:topic, vote_options_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :title, :_destroy])
  end

  def check_exist
    if Person.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)


  else
   flash[:warning] = 'You dont have any person details, please create'
      redirect_to people_new_path
  end

  end




  def people_edit_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:gender, :birthday, :country_id,:country_name,:state_id, :lang, :id, :poll_id)

end





end
```

create,update, edit and show methods are working but index. without if and else condition Polls.order is working.

update: i added model file also.

person model file:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
enum gender: [:undisclosed, :female, :male, :other]


    belongs_to :country
    belongs_to :state, optional: true
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    belongs_to :poll, optional: true

    delegate :country, :to => :poll, :allow_nil => true


end
```

poll model:

```
class Poll < ApplicationRecord
    #attr_accessible :id, :topic
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :vote_options, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :vote_options, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    validates :topic, presence: true
    has_one :person
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :person

def normalized_votes_for(option)
  votes_summary == 0 ? 0 : (option.votes.count.to_f / votes_summary) * 100
end

def votes_summary
  vote_options.inject(0) {|summary, option| summary + option.votes.count}
end


end
```

returning browser error is:

```
undefined method `person' for nil:NilClass
```

how i can filter the polls according to `current_user.person.country_id?`

thank you.

Comment: In your `index` method `@polls` is defined, but `@poll` is **not** before the if clause. Then, `@poll` is of course nil (unless it is defined in your "before" filters) and hence raises an Exception.  Is it a typo or else?

Comment: Is there a Person model? Can you also describe the relations between Poll, Person and User models?

Comment: dear MasaSakano and @rubyprince I added Poll and Person model code to above. you can check these. also thanks for your time to reserved me.

Comment: Do you have `User` model as well or just `Person` model?

Comment: yes i have. 
there is has_one :person and has_many :polls in User model.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `person' for nil:NilClass

The error says that you are calling `person` on a **nil** object. Its true because in your `index` action `@poll` is **nil** as it is **not initialized**. Setting the `@poll` should fix your problem.

```
def index
  @polls = Poll.all
  @person = Person.find_by_poll_id(params[:d]) #changed because there is no :poll_id in the params. Should be params[:id]
  @poll = Poll.find(params[:id]) #add this line

  if @poll.person.country_id == current_user.person.country_id
    @polls = Poll.where(country_id: @person.country_id).order('created_at DESC')
  else
    flash[:warning] = 'there is no polls these matching by your countries'
  end
end
```

Moreover, you have `@person = Person.find_by_poll_id(params[:poll_id])`, but the you are again doing `@poll.person` which is **unnecessary**. You can just replace `@poll.person` with `@person` like below

```
def index
  @polls = Poll.all
  @person = Person.find_by_poll_id(params[:d]) #changed because there is no :poll_id in the params. Should be params[:id]
  @poll = Poll.find(params[:id]) #add this line

  if @person.country_id == current_user.person.country_id #look here for the difference
    @polls = Poll.where(country_id: @person.country_id).order('created_at DESC')
  else
    flash[:warning] = 'there is no polls these matching by your countries'
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried it as changed your reccomend like  `@poll = Poll.find(params[:poll_id]) #add this line `  to  `@poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:id]) #add this line` otherwise it could'nt fnd the model.  so when you open index page, it is not filtering model according to `if` condition. again showing all without eliminate.

Comment: @mihraçcerrahoğlu Ofcourse it shows all polls because you have `@polls = Poll.order('created_at DESC')`. On what basis do you want to filter the polls?

Comment: that is the point dear. I need filter like ; "User should not see on index if `current_user.person.country_id` is not same with `@poll.person.country_id`
only user can see polls who he have same country id with poll. I known it is confusing you. sorry :)

Comment: also youcan check all github files in here:
[link](https://github.com/MswordArt/FBC/tree/master/app/controllers)

Comment: Index page result:
`Showing /home/mihrac/poller/app/views/polls/index.html.erb where line #7 raised:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column polls.country_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "polls".* FROM "polls" WHERE "polls"."country_id" = $...
                                            ^
: SELECT "polls".* FROM "polls" WHERE "polls"."country_id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at DESC`



...
marking error:

`<% @polls.each do |poll| %>

<div class="row justify-content-start">
<div class="col-sm-12">`



I think missing the @poll class in controller by your way.
sorry dear :(

Comment: @mihraçcerrahoğlu You said `Poll` model have `country_id`. The error says that there is no `country_id` in `polls` table

Comment: I think there is problem on my poll and person assocation. Because under poll table there is no country id. country id is under person table and It is connected by belongs_to. I will check end tell you. Thanks dear Pavan.